# Error al hacer include Warning no such file or directory

Tags: php, html

Este es el error:

> Warning: include(/carpeta/archivo.php): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory in archivo.php on line 3

Este es el código con el que me da error:

```
<?php session_start();  ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php include ("/miweb/template/head.php"); ?>
  <body class="container-fluid no-padding">
  <?php include ("/miweb/template/header.php"); ?>

  ... mas código
```

Lo que quiero incluir está en la carpeta `/miweb/template`y el archivo en el que lo quiero incluir está en `/miweb/home`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php session_start();  ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php include ("../miweb/template/head.php"); ?>
  <body class="container-fluid no-padding">
  <?php include ("../miweb/template/header.php"); ?>

  ... mas código
?>
```

Rutas relativas

Para acceder desde `miweb/home`a `/miweb/template/head.php` , tienes que poner `../template/head.php`.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con este código:

```
<?php session_start();  ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php include ("../miweb/template/head.php"); ?>
  <body class="container-fluid no-padding">
  <?php include ("../miweb/template/header.php"); ?>
```

`..` Es para bajar de directorio
`.` Hace referencia al mismo directorio

Answer (score 1):

estas direccionando mal

usa . para ir moviendote en el arbol de tu proyecto

```
<?php include ("../miweb/template/header.php"); ?>
```